# Why are Qt's CONFIG flags rtti and rtti_off only processed by qmake for Windows target

Tags: qt, qt5, cross-platform

I am working on a cross platform Qt project and recently used `dynamic_cast`, which worked just fine under Linux. But our CI could not compile the code for Windows with the error message:

```
error: ‘dynamic_cast’ not permitted with -fno-rtti
```

I found that in our project `CONFIG += rtti_off` was set. According to [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html) `rtti_off` means:

> RTTI support is disabled. By default, the compiler default is used.

There is nothing written about platform specific behavior of the flag (or at least I did not find it).

`grep -ir rtti` in Qt's mkspecs gave:

```
features/win32/rtti.prf:CONFIG -= rtti_off
features/win32/rtti.prf:QMAKE_CFLAGS += $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_RTTI_ON
features/win32/rtti.prf:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RTTI_ON
features/win32/rtti_off.prf:CONFIG -= rtti
features/win32/rtti_off.prf:QMAKE_CFLAGS += $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_RTTI_OFF
features/win32/rtti_off.prf:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RTTI_OFF
common/g++-win32.conf:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RTTI_ON  = -frtti
common/g++-win32.conf:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RTTI_OFF = -fno-rtti
common/winrt_winphone/qmake.conf:CONFIG                  = package_manifest $$CONFIG incremental flat precompile_header autogen_precompile_source debug_and_release debug_and_release_target rtti
common/winrt_winphone/qmake.conf:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RTTI_ON  = -GR
common/winrt_winphone/qmake.conf:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RTTI_OFF =
common/msvc-desktop.conf:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RTTI_ON  = -GR
common/msvc-desktop.conf:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RTTI_OFF =
```

So these flags are obviously only checked for Windows platforms.

#### My questions

- Why is it done only for Windows?
- Is this documented anywhere?

  - If so, where?
  - If not, why?

#### Edit

To clarify: I am using mingw32-gcc under Windows and gcc under Linux. Both version have the capability to deactivate RTTI using the flag `-fno-rtti`. This flag is integrated into the generated Makefile if I run qmake with target platform `win32-g++`, but not with `linux`. Hence the questions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [QTBUG-26595](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26595), which was resolved in Qt 5.12.1.

Comment: Wow, that was a long running bug (reported 2012, fixed 2018), seeing the simply fix for it. I finally can get this out of my system; was bothering me like hell.